# How to have dynamic height of TabBarView content in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What i'm trying to achieve is that, depending on the content of the `TabBarView` component, expand it to take as much space as it needs ( height ) and make the whole screen scrollable, not only the `Container` of the `TabBarView`.

In the attached example I have a `Container` which wraps the `TabBar` component. It has a fixed height at the moment because it throws errors if not. Actually that's the problem i want to fix. Get rid of that fix height, and have it somehow dinamically set.

Here is my code with comments:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:livescore/models/leaguesModel/leagues_model.dart';
import 'package:livescore/models/livescores/livescore_data_model.dart';
import 'package:livescore/pages/matchDetailsPage/components/matchDetailsHeaderWidgets/match_details_header.dart';
import 'package:livescore/pages/matchDetailsPage/components/matchDetailsStatsWidgets/match_details_stats_component.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MatchDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LeaguesModelData leaguesModelData;
  LivescoreDataModel matchDetails;
  MatchDetailsPage(this.leaguesModelData, this.matchDetails, {super.key});

  @override
  State<MatchDetailsPage> createState() => _MatchDetailsPageState();
}

class _MatchDetailsPageState extends State<MatchDetailsPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 10, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
                                                                        // whole screen background and border
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, width: 5),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              MatchDetailsHeader(
                  widget.leaguesModelData,
                  widget
                      .matchDetails),                                               // upper side of the screen, above the TabBar component
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 20, left: 20),
                child: Container(
                                                                                      // the container representing the TabBar zone
                  height: 400,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 20),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            child: TabBar(
                              labelPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                              isScrollable: true,
                              indicatorWeight: 0,
                              labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                              labelColor: Colors.white,
                              indicator: const ShapeDecoration(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(15))),
                                  color: Colors.pink),
                              tabs: const [
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Stats",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Line-up",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "H2H",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Table",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "News",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                              ],
                              controller: _tabController,
                              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: TabBarView(
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            controller: _tabController,
                            children: [
                              (widget.matchDetails.stats != null &&
                                      widget
                                          .matchDetails.stats!.data.isNotEmpty)
                                  ? MatchDetailsStatsComponent(
                                      widget.matchDetails.localTeam.data.id,
                                      widget.matchDetails.visitorTeam.data.id,
                                      widget.matchDetails.stats)
                                  : Column(
                                      children: const [
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                        Text("stats not available yet"),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried getting it work with `NestedScrollView`, `ListView`, have `ScrollPhysics` on the parent `SingleChildScrollView` and `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` on the `TabBarView` component, but didn't get it to work.

[image: This image represents the screen at the moment, when the content doens't exceeds it's limits.]

[image: This image shows the boundry error that is thrown when the content exceeds it's limits. When this is the case, i would the TabBarView container to expand and make the whole screen scrollable]

Comment: maybe just remove the `height: 400,` line? And probably also the `Expanded` then

Comment: Already tried that, it throws constraint error..

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple structure as a reference. In detail, I'm using both `TabBar` and `TabBarView` within a `NestedScrollView` which is able to take the full height. In this way, you can achieve dynamic height with `TabBarView`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
          return [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: TabBar(
                controller: tabController,
                labelColor: Colors.redAccent,
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Tab 1",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Tab 1",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Container(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: [
              /// Each content from each tab will have a dynamic height
              Container(),
              Container()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's almost what i needed, but the `TabBar` section still seems to have a fixed height, still receive a overflow error fi the content exceeds the screen height, but it s still scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Use Layout Builder as a parent of SingleChildScrollView like this and remove fixed height of Container. Follow the docs

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html